Does X11 support mice with Z axis (ie relative motion events with 3 axes), & possibly relative rotations too, ie 6DOF? If so, do Tk/Gtk/Qt?
From all the .conf files used to configure XInput, it seems X11 innately does not support a Z axis, let alone relative rotations. Is this correct? How are trackballs supported, if at all? Are spacemice supported? If so, how? Does this carry over to Tk/Gtk/Qt hence target apps using those frameworks?

If I remember correctly (and that's a "big" if, hence only a comment, not an answer), no that's not a feature of the X11 interface for input devices, and consequently also not for Tk/Gtk/Qt. What would an extra axis help when navigating a dedicatedly 2D interface? However, for certain brands of 3D input devices, there's an open source daemon that gets these 3D motion events from the hardware, and actual 3D programs like blender and freecad can make use of that.
